# Limitations of pList file on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Probably a dumb question since pList files is equal to XML but, is it a limit on how long a text inside a  - node can be?

I have a dictionary with three keys. Each key is associated with a string of maybe...400 characters, this is not a bad way of doing it right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that sounds good. 400 characters isn't really all that much in the scale of things.

There isn't really a defined 'limit' per se, although Firefox will limit you to 4096 characters per XML node (or will split a larger node into 4096 character components), so that may serve as a good starting point.